# How to generate a long-lived URL for images stored in Amazon S3 using Node.js?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I am using Amazon S3 to store images, and I need a solution to generate URLs that don't expire at all. Currently, I am using signed URLs, but they have a limited lifespan. I want to create URLs that remain valid permenently or until the image is deleted.

```
    module.exports.uploadImage = async (request, response) => {
  try {
    const file = request?.files?.image;
    if (!file) {
      return response.status(500).json({
        status: false,
        message: "Please upload Image",
        data: null,
      });
    }
    const { id } = request.body;
    const extension = file.name.split(".")[file.name.split(".").length - 1];
    const fileName = `${uuidv4()}.${extension}`;
    const currentDate = new Date().getMilliseconds();
    const key = `${id ? id : currentDate}-${uuidv4()}.${extension}`;
    await new Upload({
      client: s3Client,
      params: {
        Bucket: config.AWS_BUCKET_NAME,
        Key: key,
        Body: Buffer.from(file.data, "binary"),
        ContentType: file.mimetype,
        ContentDisposition: "inline",
      },
    }).done();

    const signedUrl = await getSignedUrl(
      s3Client,
      new GetObjectCommand({
        Bucket: config.AWS_BUCKET_NAME,
        Key: key,
      })
    );

    return response.status(201).send({ status: true, data: signedUrl });
  } catch (exc) {
    console.log(exc);
    return response.status(500).json({
      status: false,
      message: "Something went wrong",
      data: null,
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: I also wanted to do this a few weeks ago, but I configured the links to expire after 7 days (which is the maximum) for S3 pre-signed URLs.. I'm not sure AWS -SDK- offers this, but I'd be interested to see the possibilities :D

Comment: You can't, unless the objects are public.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a 'permanent' link, just use the 'normal' URL to the file without a pre-signed URL.

You will either need to:

- Make each object public, or
- Make the bucket or a subset of the bucket public by using a Bucket Policy (this is more common)

The URL would look like:

```
<bucketname>.s3.<region>.amazonaws.com/<object-key>
```